# I'm trying to change the motorspeed for my HingeJoint2D via script, it makes a Random value but doesn't apply it to the component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to change the motorspeed to a random number however it only changes it in the script component, not in the HingeJoint2D component

```
  public float speed;
  private HingeJoint2D hj;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    hj = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
    speed = Random.Range(80f, 700f);
    Debug.Log(speed);

    hj.useMotor = true;

    var motor = hj.motor;
    motor.motorSpeed = speed;


}
```

Comment: A quick google would have lead you to https://forum.unity.com/threads/hinge-joint-2d-motor.218978/ where someone asked the same question, it shows how you need to set the motor on the hingejoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to set hj at the end. change your code to

```
public float speed;
private HingeJoint2D hj;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    hj = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
    speed = Random.Range(80f, 700f);
    Debug.Log(speed);

    hj.useMotor = true;
    var motor = hj.motor;
    motor.motorSpeed = speed;
    hj.motor = motor;

}
```

In your code you created a JointMotor2D and gave it the parameter from the random function but never gave your hingeJoint the newly created motor